# What's the meaning of "distinct" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I just finished doing a listening exercise from the book [Objective Proficiency](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q120765775) and I'm now checking the transcript and the answer's book.

> For question 1-5, choose from the list (A-H) what caused each speaker to choose a particular way of dressing.

- A. feeling a distinct pressure to conform
- B. beling bullied at school
- C. being influenced by a colleague
- D. seeing an article
- E. attending a music festival
- F. visiting another country
- G. wanting to rebel against society
- H. needing to make a good impression

The following is the transcript of the speaker, the part in bold is underlined in the answer's book. The answer is A.

> The dress code at my school is fairly formal so I have to
> wear smart clothes, but I go for tops and trousers rather
> than suits and high heels. I wouldn’t want to raise too many
> eyebrows among the other staff members so no jeans. Not
> that the school is super posh or anything, **but very casual
> clothes wouldn’t go down too well**. What I wear is great
> really because I have to spend quite a bit of time **delving
> into cupboards. I tend to go for high-end clothes which
> aren’t skin tight – ones that move with me**. And they should
> last – if they were cheap, they’d soon come apart.

I have looked up all the words in the dictionary, but I still can't relate "feeling a distinct pressure to conform" with any of the underlined parts. I think "distinct" has other meaning than "different" in this context, because the meaning "different" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: distinct adjective (NOTICEABLE) [ before noun ] clearly noticeable; that certainly exists [Cambridge Dictionary, first definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/distinct). Do you understand what it means to say that the pressure to conform is clearly noticeable and certainly exists?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for the reference to the dictionary. I should have checked more than one dictionary. I only checked Longman and I didn't make the connection when I read the definition presented there. Is it possible to close this question since you already answered it?